# How to fix __init__ typeError in python3 when converting xlsx files to csv files?

Tags: python, xlsx, data-conversion

I would need to convert multiple xlsx files to csv files with python 3. I have tried doing this by very simple for loop, but I keep getting the following typeError I'm not able to fix on my own:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/media/sf_shared/convert_to_csv.py in <module>
      9         Xlsx2csv(os.path.join(in_dir, filename), os.path.join(out_dir, csv_filename))
     10 
---> 11 convert_directory( 
     12     "/media/sf_shared/all_sample_results",
     13     "/media/sf_shared/all_samples_as_csv_files")

/media/sf_shared/convert_to_csv.py in convert_directory(in_dir, out_dir)
      7     if extension == ".xlsx":
      8         csv_filename = f"{base_name}.csv"
----> 9         Xlsx2csv(os.path.join(in_dir, filename), os.path.join(out_dir, csv_filename))
     10 
     11 convert_directory(

 TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Here is the code:

```
from xlsx2csv import Xlsx2csv
import os

def convert_directory(in_dir, out_dir):
    for filename in os.listdir(in_dir):
        base_name, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
    if extension == ".xlsx":
        csv_filename = f"{base_name}.csv"
        Xlsx2csv(os.path.join(in_dir, filename), os.path.join(out_dir, csv_filename))

convert_directory(
    "/media/sf_shared/all_sample_results", 
    "/media/sf_shared/all_samples_as_csv_files")
```

Answer (score 0):

From the examples on [github](https://github.com/dilshod/xlsx2csv):

```
from xlsx2csv import Xlsx2csv
Xlsx2csv("myfile.xlsx", outputencoding="utf-8").convert("myfile.csv")
```

So:

```
Xlsx2csv(os.path.join(in_dir, filename)).convert(os.path.join(out_dir, csv_filename))
```